# Why aren't nazar and black magic considered as shirk?

Tags: shirk, sihr, evil-eye

Salam aleykum,

the question stands above. Both nazar and black magic base on another power other than Allah's, so why is it not considered as shirk? In fact, Islam even tells to be careful about it, especially black magic.
For example, why would i be able to curse somebody? Or how is it permissable that i can make nazar on somebody so that he will actually end up failing? We shouldn't be able to do that, because there's no other power than Allah.

Please no assumptions, but only answers from people who know for sure what the reason is.
Allahu alem.

Answer (score 2):

Wa alaikum as salaam

Black magic and all forms of magic are shirk. Magic involves worshipping the shaiteen and jinns by doing things that please them and disobeying Allah.

(Interpretation of the meaning). **Surah Al Baqarah ayah 102:** Sulaymaan did not disbelieve, but the Shayaateen (devils) disbelieved, teaching men magic but neither of these two (angels) taught anyone (such things) till they had said, ‘We are for trial, so disbelieve not (by learning this magic from us).’

**Magic is such that even those that practice magic are commanded to be executed in Tirmidhi and some others:**
The hadd (prescribed punishment) for the practitioner of magic is a blow with the sword (i.e., execution).

So from the above we can see that the one who performs magic **is** a kafir even if he was to pray, fast, do Hajj, gives zakah, reads The Qu'ran and makes du'aa etc because shirk cancels out ones good deeds.

And Allah knows best

Answer (score 1):

Assalamualaikum and Praise be to Allah (swt),
Black magic IS in fact something that puts a person out of Islam and IS something that makes someone a disbeliever. One who does black magic is not a believer to Allah (swt) anymore. If one who does black magic, then they should ask forgiveness from Allah (swt) and they will be forgiven

Answer (score 0):

Magic does not mean that there is any power besides Allah. In fact, Allah clearly says about magic:

> But they do not harm anyone through it (i.e. magic) except by permission of Allah. And the people learn what harms them and does not benefit them. (2:102)

And this is the same as goes to every other means of harm like swords or guns or other weapons. Nothing happens except by the permission of Allah.

However, that does not mean magic does not exist or that the evil eye does not exist any more than it means swords and guns do not exist.

The Prophet (SAW) said about the evil eye:

> The influence of an evil eye is a fact ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/39/56))